# Linux WiFi Hotspot GUI shows Not Running when I click on CREATE. Why?

Tags: linux, hotspot, manjaro

I am using `Manjaro` as my OS and I had installed Linux-wifi-hostpot through https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot

In terminal, it showed transaction finished successfully. But when I opened its GUI aned clicked on **Create Hotspot**, it threw *Command not found or exited with error status* in the termninal and it still said *Not Running* in the GUI.

It says `Your adapter can not be a station(i.e. connected) and an AP at the same time.`

What is its possible cause and appropriate solution? Can anyone assist me out?

PS: Since I am not eligible to post images, so I am putting thr link to the complete question I have asked over Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495965/linux-wifi-hotspot-gui-shows-not-running-when-i-click-on-create-why

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. Your WiFi adapter can create an AP but cannot be one and be connected to another AP at the same time.

Comment: I know but I would like to have a possible solution for the same. I am connected to internet through wifi and at the same time, I gotta keep my hotspot on in order to use that internet on other devices too. But since my linux-wifi-hotspot even on clicking says Not Running, what could I possibly do?

Comment: There is no solution, at least not in Linux with Linux drivers. There's a software for Windows that claims to overcome this but I haven't tested. The solution for you is to connect to the internet with something else (e.g. Ethernet) so the WiFi device can be an AP, end of story.

Answer (score 0):

try downloading XDG-desktop-portal-gnome it works.my hotspot was working fine until when i uninstalled xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.reverse it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).